# Gently reboot Windows 7 without display

Tags: windows-7

In Arch Linux, I'd do any number of things in my current situation, the last of which being REISUB. Unfortunately I'm not using Arch Linux specifically because I didn't want to deal with what I thought might has been a software bug which caused me to REISUB my system.

Pretty much my monitor went dead, but sound was still coming from my monitors. I'm hoping it's just the nVidia 570 showing it's age. My ASuS mother board's lights read AA, so as far it knows nothing is wrong (not memory or CPU). Also, I hit ctrl+alt+delete which stopped the music, so I have keyboard control.

In anycase, I digress. I know Windows 7 lacks a REISUB like feature. That was the first thing I searched for. Searching for some alternative, however was fruitless as well.

So my question, finally, is "How can I gently reboot my Windows 7 OS without the use of a display". I seem to have keyboard control.

Comment: Try Windows key, then U, then U again. That should work unless there's anything in the start menu starting with a 'U'. Ah, sorry, u/u is shutdown... Win + U + R to reboot [with the same caveat]

Comment: I'm pretty sure I have uninstall probrams. Also, I'm in the ctrl+alt+del screen, or should be, so I can't bring up the start menu. If I'm not in the ctrl+alt+del screen than I have another set of issues.

Comment: Esc will leave the ctrl/alt/delete screen

Comment: I hit esc. I then pressed Windows then U then U. I wouldn't mind shutting down. Since this seems to be a clear case of faulty hardware, I'd like to disconnect those HDDs that contain data going back to the 90s. Having backups are good. Not needing them is better.

Answer (score 5):

Type the following. If you just want to shut down change the /r to /s. The /t 00 is not needed but if left out will cause the computer to wait 30-60 seconds before starting to reboot. The /f forces it to shutdown even if programs are complaining about needing to save.

Win key + r
shutdown.exe /r /f /t 00
enter

Comment: Thank you very much! That worked exactly as I had hoped. The only thing better is if it also fixed my computer. Also, sorry that I can't up vote your answer in a meaningful way. My rep is too low.