# Reboot Windows 10 gracefully while screen is locked (REISUB for Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, reboot, lock-screen, wake-up

I have a Windows 10 laptop. When I am at home, it's connected to and external monitor via HDMI.

Today I needed the laptop with me in the city, so first I disconnected all the cables, and then I sent it to sleep.

When on the train, I have woken it up from sleep. The lock screen has appeared, with the big time and date displayed near the bottom left corner.

At this point, I normally press `Ctrl` to bring up the login form, but this time it did not trigger any change. Neither did pressing `Enter`, `Esc`, or pressing briefly the power button. It was stuck on the lock screen with the date display, but no login form.

On Linux, I would have gone for the `Alt` + `PrintScreen` + REISUB key sequence. But on Windows 10, not knowing any better, I had to restart by pressing the power button for several seconds, until the shutdown occurred.

But I know that it is suboptimal for the lifespan of the disk, and the filesystem on it.

How could I have rebooted Windows 10 more gracefully in this situation?

(I have found [this](https://superuser.com/q/1171007/1257174) and [this](https://superuser.com/q/426666/1257174) threads, but they both assume that I am logged in and have access to either the start menu or the `run` dialog; so they are of no help while one is being stuck on an unresponsive lock screen.)